# Infragistics WebDataGrid don't show in my host browser but show in VS

Tags: infragistics, asp.net-4.0, webdatagrid

I am uploading a web form application asp.net 4 to plesk host.everything is ok but Infragistics  WebDataGrid don't show in my host browser but show in VS( visual studio 2019).so what is the solution?
Infragistics2023

Infragistics controls must work in host browser.